# Jetty 9.3.4 not working with integration tests

Tags: java, maven, jetty, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm running integration tests using jersey, jetty 9.x, jetty-maven-plugin and the maven-failsafe-plugin.

Integration tests worked well with jetty 9.2.0.M0 specified in jetty-maven-plugin. When using version 9.3.4.RC1, jetty starts, but no integration tests are run.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-integration-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>jetty-integration-test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>jetty-integration-test</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.0.M0</version>
        <!--TODO: 9.3.4.RC1 does not verify integration tests as 9.2.0.M0-->
        <configuration>
          <httpConnector>
            <port>8081</port>
          </httpConnector>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <contextPath>/</contextPath>
          <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
          <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
              <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>integration-test</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>my.example.jetty_integration_test.App</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Thats a minimal web-service example:
App.java:

```
package my.example.jetty_integration_test;


import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class App extends ResourceConfig {
    /**
     * Register JAX-RS application components.
     */
    public App() {
        register(WebService.class);
    }
}
```

WebService.java:

```
package my.example.jetty_integration_test;


import ...

// Browse to http://localhost:8081/rest/webservice

@Path("webservice")
public class WebService {


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

And a minimal integration test that shows the problem:
AppITCase.java

```
package my.example.jetty_integration_test;

import ...

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppITCase {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        try {
            httpClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void canCallWebService() {
        // Given.
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8081/rest/webservice");
        // When.
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = tryHttpRequest(httpGet);
        String text = tryReadHttpBody(httpResponse);
        // Then.
        assertEquals("Got it!", text.trim());

    }

    private CloseableHttpResponse tryHttpRequest(HttpUriRequest httpRequest) {
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return httpResponse;
    }

    private String tryReadHttpBody(HttpResponse httpResponse){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
            inputStream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            return new String(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When switching between the two jetty versions in the pom.xml, mvn clean verify will work or it will not run any IT case...
How can I run integration tests using the newer jetty version?

Edit:
After jetty started, failsafe does not make any output to the console (It does as usual for jetty 9.2.0.M0).
Console output from maven clean verify with jetty 9.3.4.RC1:

```
~/workspace/jetty-integration-test$ mvn clean verify
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jetty-integration-test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/target/jetty-integration-test.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.4.RC1:run (start-jetty) @ jetty-integration-test >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jetty-integration-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.4.RC1:run (start-jetty) @ jetty-integration-test <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.4.RC1:run (start-jetty) @ jetty-integration-test ---
2015-10-08 21:44:42.385:INFO::main: Logging initialized @6255ms
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: jetty-integration-test
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src/main/webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/target/classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/target/tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:///home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = /home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/src/main/webapp
2015-10-08 21:44:42.553:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.4.RC1
2015-10-08 21:44:45.073:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@4cdb8504{/,file:///home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///home/alex/workspace/jetty-integration-test/src/main/webapp/}
2015-10-08 21:44:45.101:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@25e70455{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2015-10-08 21:44:45.103:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @8974ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Comment: What do you mean by "will not run any IT case" ? Failsafe runs your IT cases, so what's the Maven output you get from Failsafe ? Have you run a mvn -X clean verify ?

Comment: I added the console output for jetty  9.3.4.RC1  above. "mvn -X clean verify" also does not produce any output from the failsafe plugin ...

Comment: your jetty server seems to be run in non daemon mode. Try with release version 9.3.4.v20151007 instead of RC1.

Comment: Jetty `9.2.0.M0` is a milestone release (a beta if you wish).
Its not a final or stable version to be basing anything off of.  Jetty `9.3.4.v20151007` is the latest stable release, use that.

Comment: Yes thats correct. Atm 9.3.4.v2015007 is not available on repo.maven.apache.org, so I used the release candidate of jetty 9.3.4. But theres no sense in using a milestone release for 9.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `jetty-maven-plugin:run` means you are running your `<packaging>war</packaging>` project with Jetty.  Your project is sitting deployed and ready for you to hit it with a Browser (or really, anything not inside of the Maven process).

When you are done you simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop that Jetty instance.

Perhaps you are thinking of `jetty-maven-plugin:start` (and its associated `jetty-maven-plugin:stop`) which is meant to start Jetty and not block waiting for the Jetty process to be stopped (or exited)

See https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-start-goal

Comment: this does not explain why he gets the expected behaviour with jetty 9.2

Comment: You are basing your experience on an unstable/beta/milestone release of Jetty 9.2, when the maven plugin was undergoing large refactoring.  Chalk this up to accidental reliance on a bug/unintended behavior.

Comment: Specifying <goal>start<goal> instead of <goal>run<goal> in the pre-integration-test phase runs the integration tests with jetty 9.3.4.RC1.