# How to start a daemon thread as soon as the jetty server starts

Tags: multithreading, maven, jetty

I have a requirement on starting daemon thread once the jetty server starts, I have a idea on it,

1. when you issue mvn jetty:run on the terminal it will compile and run the jetty server.
2. on the terminal you will see info as :Jetty server started, now is there is a way to find out whether the server started or not. for ex. if the jetty server object name is "server" then by checking server.isStarted() or not will work or not.
3. How to start a daemon thread(java) once the jetty server starts.

I am trying to start a daemon thread once server.isStarted() is true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jetty 9.3.4 not working with integration tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023669/jetty-9-3-4-not-working-with-integration-tests)

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Build waits at Jetty start when running integration tests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32828498/775715)